# Java how to sort a List by a field with locale?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am trying to sort a list by a field with a specific locale. How can I combine the following statements?

```
names.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(AClass::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr","TR"));
coll.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a variant of `Comparator.comparing` that takes two arguments. The second argument is a Comparator, so you can just pass the `Collator` instance as the second argument:

```
Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr","TR"));
coll.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
List<AClass> sorted = names.stream()
                           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(AClass::getName,coll))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Model> sortedModelList = unSortedModelList.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Model::getField,Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr","TR"))))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```